# How to update / push data to an empty array in Firestore - Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with React and Firestore. When a user is registered I save an empty array `{chats : []}` on their profile. When a user compose a message to a another user, during that time I want to push some data to this `chats` array. One thing should be kept in mind, that this specific array shouldn't get overwritten. Simply, a new value should be pushed to it.

**All I can do is**

```js
db.collection('Users').doc(userid).update({
  chats: ['somevalue']
})
```

Note : My method overwrites the data of the whole array.

**The Firestore User Data Sample**

```js
db.collection('Users').doc(this.state.user.uid).set({
  name: `${this.state.fname} ${this.state.lname}`,
  email: this.state.email,
  time: new Date().getTime(),
  id: this.state.user.uid,
  address: this.state.place,
  username: this.state.username,
  bio: this.state.bio,
  img: this.state.imgURL,
  chats: [] //To add the chats list to the user profile
}).then(() => {
  console.log("User Info Added...");
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, and I think its the easiest way to achieve it. You can find out how it works through the comments.

All I did is :

1. Get the `chats[]` arrays from the `Users` object
2. Push New Values to the retrieved arrays
3. Update the `chats[]` array with new updated values pushed to it.

```js
//Get the Following Users through the specific document ID
Promise.all([
  db.collection('Users').doc(new Cookies().getCookie('uid')).get(),
  db.collection('Users').doc(this.props.data['0'].userId).get()
]).then(e => {
  //Get the Chats array from the object
  let c = e.map(lists => lists.data().chats)
  //push new values which is 'loc' in my case to the Chats arrays
  c.forEach(e => {
    e.push(loc)
  })

  //Make two Other promises to update the chat arrays with the upated values.
  Promise.all([
    db.collection('Users').doc(new Cookies().getCookie('uid')).update({
      chats: c[0]
    }),
    db.collection('Users').doc(this.props.data['0'].userId).update({
      chats: c[1]
    }),
  ]).then(e => {
    console.log("Docments Updated")
  })

})
```